# Windows Phone 8 scheduled agent update custom interval (more than 30 minutes)

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

There are couple of apps at the Windows Phone Store which are automatically updating phone lock screen by a custom interval, lets say 1, 2, 4 or more hours.
I did some search over internet to find some articles or best practice to implement custom update interval, which is bigger than 30 minutes but without any result. 
Maybe you know some code snippets or reference on articles ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have already found, the periodic agents are invoked once every 30 mins. However, you can simply do nothing until your desired update period has passed then execute your update.

You already have access to your app's isolated storage from within your background agent. You can simply store a counter in some file to track the time that has passed and once it meets your requirement you can execute your update and reset the counter.